# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ACL_PUBLIC_READ'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I downloaded AWS SDK and stored it in the same directory of this file, but every tyme this simple script gives this error:

```
"Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ACL_PUBLIC_READ'"
```

This script is for uploading a simple png image on s3:

```
require 'aws.phar';
$bucket='example';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'mykey',
    'secret' => 'mysecretkey'
));


$client->putObject($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $bucket , 'file.png', S3Client::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That constant doesn't exist in SDK 2.x. I think you're looking for this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.Enum.CannedAcl.html